# How does yarn upgrade's pattern flag work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, package-managers

[The examples](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/) show like:

```
yarn upgrade --pattern gulp
yarn upgrade left-pad --pattern "gulp|grunt"
yarn upgrade --latest --pattern "gulp-(match|newer)"
```

But when trying this with `yarn upgrade --pattern eslint` or `--pattern "eslint"` or `--pattern "eslint-"` nothing happens.

It's not clear what is and is not a valid pattern from the limited examples.

Our packages have newer versions available within the ranges specified in our `package.json`, but they're only upgraded if we run `yarn upgrade` without any flags, which makes upgrading exceedingly difficult.

Unfortunately `yarn upgrade-interactive` does not work in our environment.